# Matching EmbeddedDocument in EmbeddedDocumentList

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

so I have this test data for instance in mongo, Cart model:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55eb513c516ddc8fa6e68886"),
    "user" : ObjectId("55e3f236516ddc78296968be"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55eb10b8516ddc7508dba7c2"),
            "quantity" : 1,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-09-05T20:32:16.527Z"),
            "coupons" : ObjectId("55eb10cd516ddc751d3d5e25"),
            "order_type" : [
                "in_store",
                "curbside"
            ]
        },
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55eb10b8516ddc7508dba7cc"),
            "quantity" : 1,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-09-05T20:32:16.527Z"),
            "coupons" : ObjectId("55eb10cd516ddc751d3d5e25")
        },
        {
            "item" : ObjectId("55eb10b8516ddc7508dba7c8"),
            "quantity" : 1,
            "added_date" : ISODate("2015-09-05T20:32:16.527Z"),
            "coupons" : ObjectId("55eb10cd516ddc751d3d5e25")
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are my models:

```
class CartItem(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    item = mongoengine.ReferenceField('Item')
    quantity = mongoengine.IntField()
    added_date = mongoengine.DateTimeField( default=timezone.now() )
    coupons = mongoengine.ReferenceField('Coupon')
    order_type = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.StringField(choices=ORDER_TYPE_CHOICES))

class Cart(mongoengine.Document):
    user = mongoengine.ReferenceField('User')
    items = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(CartItem)
    savings = mongoengine.DecimalField(precision=2, default=0)
```

Now I want to be able to get **CartItems** that have for instance only order_type of **"in_store"**. So I something like this:

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(id="id")
items = cart.items
curbside_items = items.filter(order_type="curbside")
```

This does not return anything. So I try this:

```
curbside_items = items.filter(order_type__math="curbside")
```

But that does not return me anything as well.So my question is how can I do this in mongoengine.Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoEngine uses the ["double underscore"](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries) for properties in translation to the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form of MongoDB queries. So the "parent" of the property you are looking for is "items", which means you reference with the complete path like so:

```
Cart.objects.filter(items__order_type="in_store")
```

Where the document contains "in_store" as an `order_type` entry within the `items` array. Note that this returns "whole documents" and not just the matching entries. There are other ways to handle that in reponses.

One way is with a "raw" result using the underlying pymongo driver:

```
Cart._get_collection().find(
    { "items.order_type": "in_store" },
    { "items.$": 1 }
)
```

Which utilizes the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in order to returned the matched array element only.

Or for "mutiple" matches then you need `.aggregate()`:

```
Cart._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "items.order_type": "in_store"
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$order_type", "in_store" ] }, "in_store" ] },
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

Or making more sense in future releases via `$filter`:

```
Cart._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "items.order_type": "in_store"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "items": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$items",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.order_type", "in_store" ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Standard mongoengine queries in the "djangoesque" line do not support such operations, and only return the whole document unmodifed. The exception is made for `$slice` where there is an option to do just what it's native MongoDB counterpart does as well.

Comment: That gets me the cart, but I would like to get the CartItem. I updated the post to show what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: @Brenden1995 You did not really digest what I said did you? Mongoengine does not support the sort of "projection" as generally offerred by mongodb queries. If you just want to get the "matching item" then you need to do it in code, as mongoengine will not just retrieve the matched item from the array "only". It needs the whole array that is present in the document. Or you can use "raw" queries instead and retrieve basic python objects directly from the underlying pymongo driver.

Comment: @Brenden1995 How about you read everything above. There is more than enough there to make every case clear.